# Login de 2 tipos de usuarios con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi curso escolar y estoy un poco desesperando porque lo he intentado muchas veces pero no me sale, quiero con una página de login, poder iniciar sesión o con un usuario de tipo profesor o administrador y que dependiendo del tipo de usuario me redirija a x pantalla. Si me podéis echar una mano se agradecería bastante, gracias!
Mi código hasta ahora es este:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include "../conexion.php";
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
 $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
 $passw=$_POST['passw'];
 $profe="profesor";
 $admin="administrador";}

 $query="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND passw='$passw' AND tipo='$profe'";
 $run_profe=mysql_query($query);

 $query_admin="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND passw='$passw' AND tipo='$admin'";
 $run_admin=mysql_query($query_admin);

 if(mysql_num_rows($run_profe==1)
 {
   echo "<script>window.open('../principal_profe.html'.'_self')</script>";
 }
 else if(mysql_num_rows($run_admin)==1)
 {
   echo "<script>window.open('../principal_admin.html'.'_self')</script>";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "<script>alert('Usuario o contraseña es incorrecta.')</script>";
 }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
 <h2>Login</h2>
</div>
<form method="post" action="">
 <div class="input-group">
  <label>Usuario</label>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" value="">
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <label>Contraseña</label>
  <input type="password" name="passw">
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register_btn">Entrar</button>
 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola jamiechwr y bienvenido a este gran foro de la programación. Yo hice hace un tiempo algo parecido. Primero valida que el usuario exista en tu bbdd, y después, en otra consulta, busca si ese user es profe o admin. Así, si es de uno llevalo a una página y si es de otro llevalo a otra. Por otro lado, te recomiendo que utilices mysqli o mysql pdo, porque mysql está en desuso. Además, si es un login, deberías poner en tu página primero el código html y después el código php.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla gracias por contestar. He intentado hacer eso, incluso con un login.php aparte pero en vez de redirigirse, lo que hacía era mostrar el código del archivo login.php y no sabía por qué exactamente, entonces lo he probado de esta forma. Es que hasta ahora no había tocado php entonces ando un poco perdido en comparación de con otro lenguajes.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Login PHP 2 usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264119/login-php-2-usuarios)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores en tu código, el principal y por el que te esta saltando el error es porque te falta un paréntesis:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($run_profe **)** ==1)
```

Por otro lado, tienes una comprobación `if(isset($_POST['login']))`, que nunca te llegará a *true* porque no tienes ningún elemento con el `name="login"` en el formulario, para resolverlo deberías agregarlo a la etiqueta `form` de esta manera: `<form name="login" method="post" action="">`

Por otro lado no se con que versión de **PHP** estas trabajando, pero las funciones `mysql_num_rows()` y `mysql_query()` están declaradas obsoletas en **PHP** 5.5.0 y eliminadas en **PHP** 7.0.0

Comment: Gracias, es que ya te digo, soy bastante nuevo a php y ando un poco perdido la verdad.

Comment: ¿Con qué puedo remplazar los mysql_query?

Comment: con mysqli_query, acá tienes la documentación: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php y para el mysql_num_rows() igual tienes el mysqli_num_rows(), acá tienes la documentación = https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Al final hecho un borrado y cuenta nueva digamos y lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

Comment: <?php
session_start();
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("proyecto_final");

$query = "SELECT Tipo FROM registro WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Passw='$passw'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);

 echo $result;

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row["Tipo"]=='Profesor'){
    header ("Location: ../principal_profe.html");
    exit();
}
   else if($row["Tipo"]=='Admin'){
    header ("Location: ../principal_admin.html");
       exit();
   }
   
   else{
       header ("Location: Index.html");
       exit();
   }
 mysqli_close($conn);