# Login PHP 2 usuarios

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero que al iniciar sesión con el tipo de usuario que sea de los 2, redirige a las páginas indicadas, pero no consigo que funcione. Echarme una mano si podéis porfavor!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("proyecto_final");

    $query = "SELECT Tipo FROM registro WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Passw='$passw'";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);

    echo $result;

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row["Tipo"]=='Profesor'){
        header ("Location: ../principal_profe.html");
        exit();
    }
    else if($row["Tipo"]=='Admin'){
        header ("Location: ../principal_admin.html");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        header ("Location: Index.html");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Login de 2 tipos de usuarios con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264092/login-de-2-tipos-de-usuarios-con-php). Mismo usuario, pregunta pacticamente igual.

Answer (score 2):

Una principal cosa que veo es que estas mezclando `mysql_*` `con mysqli_*`. La extensión `mysql_*` fue declarada obsoleta en **PHP 5.5.0** y eliminada en **PHP 7.0.0**.

Por lo que tu conexión la pondría así:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto_final");
```

En la consulta, en el método [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) le estas pasando solo la *query*, te falta indicarle tu variable `$conn`(La conexión a la base de datos).

```
$query = "SELECT Tipo FROM registro WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Passw='$passw'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Una vez obtengamos los datos de la consulta, procedemos a verificar lo que queramos:

```
if($row["Tipo"]=="Profesor"){
    . . .
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto_final");

    $query = "SELECT Tipo FROM registro WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Passw='$passw'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo $result;

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row["Tipo"]=="Profesor"){
        header ("Location: ../principal_profe.html");
        exit();
    }
    else if($row["Tipo"]=="Admin"){
        header ("Location: ../principal_admin.html");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        header ("Location: Index.html");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar @marioguiber Se me escapó la i al final de mysqli_connect la verdad, pero aún habiéndolo corregido todo sigue sin llevarme a las páginas seleccionadas. En las páginas a las que van a acceder necesito añadir algún código PHP?

Comment: ¿Qué error te arroja? es posible que el header te esté provocando problemas. Prueba poniendo un echo "Profesor" y echo  "Admin" (donde corresponda) y luego comenta los header ("Location: ..) . Ingresa con cada contraseña y ve si te devuelve las etiquetas correctas. Si es asi, el problema es de la redirección , si no te retorna nada o algo incorrecto, el problema es de la conexión.